# error C2259: "Derived" cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++, boost-python, pure-virtual

how can i called the pure virtual  function in derived class by using  boost python .Error i got is that cannot instantiate the abstract base class. The sample code is as :

```
class Base
{
public: 
    virtual int test() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    int  test()
    {
        int  a = 10;
        return a;
    }
};

struct  BaseWrap : Base, wrapper<Base>
{
    Int  test() 
    {
        return this->get_override(“test”)();
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Pure_Virtual) 
{
    Class_<BaseWrap, boost::noncopyable>(“Base”, no_init)
    .def(“test”, pure_virtual($Base::test)
    ;

    Class_<Derived, bases<Base> >(“Derived”)
    .def(“test”, &Derived::test)
    ;   
}
```

Comment: wrapper is keyword from Boost python.

Comment: Any chance for a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) with the example usage and errors?

Comment: Problem is that how to write the statement  in BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE for accessing test function of derived class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure virtual functions are invoked the same way as non-pure virtual functions.  The only difference is that a function exposed as a pure virtual Python method will raise a `RuntimeError` when invoked.

The initial posted code has various syntax problems, so it is difficult to identify exactly what the problem is.  However, here is a complete example based on the original code:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

namespace python = boost::python;

class Base
{
public:
  virtual int test() = 0;
  virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived
  : public Base
{
public:
  int test() { return 10; }
};

struct BaseWrap
  : Base, python::wrapper<Base>
{
  int test() 
  {
    return this->get_override("test")();
  }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example) 
{
  python::class_<BaseWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Base")
    .def("test", python::pure_virtual(&BaseWrap::test))
    ;

  python::class_<Derived, python::bases<Base> >("Derived")
    .def("test", &Derived::test)
    ;   
}
```

And its usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> derived = example.Derived()
>>> derived.test()
10
>>> class Spam(example.Base):
...     pass
... 
>>> s = Spam()
>>> s.test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Pure virtual function called
>>> class Egg(example.Base):
...     def test(self):
...         return 42
... 
>>> e = Egg()
>>> e.test()
42
```

When `test()` is invoked on a type that inherits from `example.Base` but does not implement a `test()` method, Boost.Python will raise a `RuntimeError` indicating a pure virtual function has been invoked.  Hence, `test()` on a `Spam` object raises an exception, where as `test()` on an `Egg` object is properly dispatched.